# Creating polygons with sharp angles does not work

Tags: r, rgl

When I want to plot polygons using `rgl`, for certain coordinate pairs, I get an error:

```
# polygon data
xyz <- structure(c(5.90000000002328, 6, 6.20000000001164, 5.90000000002328, 
12.2999999998137, 12.2999999998137, 12.2999999998137, 12.2999999998137, 
7.45599365234375, 7.6009521484375, 7.7039794921875, 7.45599365234375
), dim = 4:3, dimnames = list(c("p1", "p2", "p3", "p1"), c("x", 
"y", "Z")))

# plotting
polygon3d(
      x = as.numeric(xyz[,1]),
      y = as.numeric(xyz[,2]),
      z = as.numeric(xyz[,3]), col = "red")

> Error in processOutside(i) : Cannot triangulate polygon
```

However, for other polygons, it works, e.g. for:

```
# working polygon
xyz <- structure(c(3.70000000001164, 3, 3.09999999997672, 3.70000000001164, 
12.2999999998137, 12, 12, 12.2999999998137, 8.74200439453125, 
8.91094970703125, 8.990966796875, 8.74200439453125), dim = 4:3, dimnames = list(
    c("p1", "p2", "p3", "p1"), c("x", "y", "Z")))
```

I thought it might be because of the proximity of the points, but after multiplying the points with 100 or rounding decimal points, I still get an error. Why do I get this error? Does this have to do with too sharp angles?

Comment: Maybe that's because all three points have the same y coordinate?

Comment: @swaps1 when one of the y coordinates is changed, the error goes away for me. I can't explain why though. I wonder if it goes from being an invalid polygon to a valid one, and if so, if there's a function that can check for validity?

Comment: The docs say that it uses `x` and `y` coordinates to define the polygon, but your `y` coordinate is constant.  You need to use `coords = c(1,3)` to get it to work.  It should probably do this automatically, as `triangulate` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for `polygon3d` say that it uses the `coords` argument (default `1:2`) to choose the coordinates to use for triangulating the polygon.  Since your `y` coordinate is constant, this creates a degenerate triangle and triangulation fails.

To fix this, specify `coords = c(1, 3)` to tell it to use `x` and `z` coordinates instead, i.e.

```
polygon3d(
      x = as.numeric(xyz[,1]),
      y = as.numeric(xyz[,2]),
      z = as.numeric(xyz[,3]), 
      coords = c(1,3), col = "red")
```

A change is in the works to make this choice automatically; you should soon be able to use your original code if you install the development version of `rgl` (version 0.109.15 or greater).  Use

```
remotes::install_github("dmurdoch/rgl")
```

It will require a full set of tools (compilers, etc.) to run.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know `rgl` works like this. Now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

The `rgl` manual mentions that

> Polygons must be non-degenerate and quadrilaterals must be entirely in
> one plane and convex, or the results are undefined.

However, I don't see how yours can be degenerate. I would plot using another method:

```
xyz <- structure(c(5.90000000002328, 6, 6.20000000001164, 5.90000000002328, 
                   6, 12.2999999998137, 12.2999999998137, 12.2999999998137, 
                   7.45599365234375, 7.6009521484375, 7.7039794921875, 7.45599365234375
), dim = 4:3, dimnames = list(c("p1", "p2", "p3", "p1"), c("x", "y", "Z")))
x <- as.numeric(xyz[,1])
y <- as.numeric(xyz[,2])
z <- as.numeric(xyz[,3])

plot3d(x,y,z)
segments3d(x[1:2],y[1:2],z[1:2],col="blue",lwd=2)
segments3d(x[2:3],y[2:3],z[2:3],col="blue",lwd=2)
segments3d(x[c(1,3)],y[c(1,3)],z[c(1,3)],col="blue",lwd=2)

xyz <- structure(c(3.7, 3, 3.09, 3.7, 
                   12.3, 12, 12, 12.3, 8.74, 
                   8.91, 9, 8.74), dim = 4:3, dimnames = list(
                     c("p1", "p2", "p3", "p1"), c("x", "y", "Z")))
x <- as.numeric(xyz[,1])
y <- as.numeric(xyz[,2])
z <- as.numeric(xyz[,3])
plot3d(x,y,z)

segments3d(x[1:2],y[1:2],z[1:2],col="red",lwd=2)
segments3d(x[2:3],y[2:3],z[2:3],col="red",lwd=2)
segments3d(x[c(1,3)],y[c(1,3)],z[c(1,3)],col="red",lwd=2)
```

[image]

[image]